# Android Shadow Effect on EditText Field.

Tags: android

[I need to add a shadow effect a the one shown in the image, below the blue color edit text field. How should I achieve the following.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6uk9.png)

Comment: Please refer to this: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CardView` and set its elevation to create a shadow:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <!-- Insert desired views here -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Note that the `CardView` extends `FrameLayout` so it will stack its children if there are more than one. Add a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` inside the `CardView` and add the views (EditText's in your case) inside one of those for more flexibility.

Comment: When I am using the CardView Object. it say the following class could not be found - android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Comment: @AmanAgarwal You need to add the design support library to your module's build.gradle, as such: `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`. Instead of 23.1.0, use  version you are using in your project.